# I'm confused, what's the easiest way to install Ruby 1.9.2 on OS X?

Tags: ruby, macos

My current version is ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin10]

Answer (score 5):

Step 1. Install Homebrew: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

This enables you to install various *IX projects on a mac. You may need to install xcode as part of this, so you may need your OS X disc to hand. Homebrew is useful for many other things - a good thing to have installed anyway.

Step 2. Install Ruby Version Manager:

```
brew install rvm
```

Step 3. Install whichever Ruby version you want. This means you can have multiple Ruby installations (with their own sets of rubygems) running independently of one another. for 1.9.2 try this:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

If you get a 'readline' error, try this:

```
rvm package install readline
rvm remove 1.9.2
rvm install 1.9.2 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

You should now be able to do this to test your ruby version:

```
ruby --version
```

To switch back to another version of ruby, just use the rvm command.

Answer (score 3):

You can try rvm to install whatever the version of ruby.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you summarized how to install rvm and then how to install 1.9.2 under it. At the least you should include a link to rvm install instructions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should give a simple instruction about how to install rvm and ruby under it.

Answer (score 0):

if you will get error

> undefined method `path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)

during command

```
~/rubygems-1.3.7 $ ruby setup.rb
```

remove ruby and rubygems with command

```
sudo autoremove ruby
sudo autoremove rubygem
```

ant try to install all again

Comment: That didn't work for me, I got "bash: ./install: No such file or directory" on the second command.